# Prevent .cls file extension from compiling in VS 2017

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, msbuild

I am working with SecureTeam AgileDotNet obfuscation tool and would like to keep its configuration files (which are .cls extensions..) within my solution, however when added as Solution Items AND when they are opened in VS editor, they cause errors:

```
Error   BC30636 '>' expected.   Miscellaneous Files D:\code\git\repos\my-path-to-agiledotnet-config.cls 2   Active
```

This is quite annoying. They are xml files with a .cls extension (reminds of classic VB class files), so I'm wondering if the compiler is treating them as such.

Is there a way for me to prevent this either through VS settings or (preferably) through my project/solution settings?

Comment: Be wary of tool vendors that make dumb choices.  Right-click the .cls file, Open With.  You have a choice, XML editor would be sane.  Or whatever tool is supposed to edit these files through "Pick an app".  Click Set as Default.  Select the .cls again, in the Properties window change the Build Action from Compile to None.

Comment: @JohnZaj, Any update for this issue? Have you resolve this issue? If not, please let me know the latest status of this problem.

Comment: No, no resolution. I'm no longer on the project - it went over the wall :). It's really a problem with the vendor IMHO. I put in an enhancement request to have their extensions not be 'cls'...seems reasonable and they understand. not sure they'll implement it, I'm an outlier to them in that I want this to work as seamlessly as possible so I don't have to document all these gotchas...

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way for me to prevent this either through VS settings or (preferably) through my project/solution settings?

If you just want to prevent .cls file extension from compiling in VS, you can accept Hans`s suggestion:"**in the Properties window change the Build Action from Compile to None.**"

[image]

**However**, those compile errors still in the Error List after you change the `Build Action` to `None`. If there are no any other errors in your project, your will get a build succeeded message, the errors will in the `Error List`. And you can run or debug the project. But If there are other errors, those errors are mixed in `.cls` related error messages.

Since Visual Studio has no support for VB6 code. If you are add `.cls` file type in the VB project, Visual Studio will handle this file as `VB.NET` files. It provides syntax highlighting that is mostly-useful, as `VB6` and `VB.Net` share significant syntax. As far as I know there is no way to get the best of the two worlds so far except renaming `.cls` file to `.txt`.